# How to compute probability of success after n Bernoulli trials, in R, using a loop structure?

Tags: r

I am trying to learn R programming and I am having trouble with a problem. I am trying to set a probability of success $p$ and find out what the chance of success is for $n$ trials. Basically a Bernoulli trial but I am trying to implement it myself using a `while` loop to learn R better.

I know that the loop structure in R is similar to many languages, i.e., `while (condition) {body}` but not sure how to go about accomplishing my task.

Comment: If I understand what you intend to do, a `for` loop might be a better fit to what you want to do.

Comment: Do you seek the chance of one or more successes in $n$ trials? Hint: That is $1 - $ the chance of zero successes in $n$ trials, and no loop is needed for calculation.

Comment: You did not describe what you are actually trying to accomplish...if you want to know how to use loop structures in R search on google. If you have a loop and it is not doing what you want it to do, please post your code.

Comment: It would have been much more friendly to the new-user OP to move this to StackOverflow itself, where it is totally on-topic as an R programming question.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you are trying to do, but consider all of these approaches:

```
# Using built in R functions
dbinom(1:10, size=10, prob=0.6)

# Using apply
sapply(1:10, function(x){ choose(10,x) * p^x * (1-p)^(n-x)} )

# Using a for-loop
result <- NULL
n <- 10
p <- 0.6
for(i in 1:10) {
  result[i] <- choose(10,i) * p^i * (1-p)^(n-i)
}

# Using a while-loop
result <- NULL
n <- 10
p <- 0.6
i <- 1
while(i<=10){
  result[i] <- choose(10,i) * p^i * (1-p)^(n-i)
  i <- i+1
}
```

Now go forth and learn!!!

http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOU2XLYxmsIK9qQfztXeybpHvru-TrqAP

http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html